# Cucumber is not recognizing defined steps "Undefined Steps"

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I can't execute a simple test with cucumber for a project. I am on Intellij 13 Community, with cucumber plugin.

I wrote my feature file in my features directory, I have also implemented my steps creating them with the help of the plugin. My steps in the feature files are recognized by intellij, which can navigate and go to the step implementation.
When I try to run my scenario, if fails stating "Undefined step". Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is how i organized my project :

[image: Project setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you are trying to run the feature from Idea. It also sounds as if you have some issue with the wiring of your project.

My approach would be to start with something that works and then modify it to suit your needs. A project that works is the Java skeleton provided by the Cucymber team. Download or clone it from GitHub: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

You should be able to build this project using Maven, Ant, or Gradle. It will also be possible to open it using IntelliJ IDEA and modify it to suit your needs.